# Using events for a dimmed variable

Tags: vb.net, events, variables

How can I use the event for a dimmed variable that is NOT a control.
This is my dimmed variable:

```
Dim engine As New Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine
```

I want to use the event "engine.SpeechRecognized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way you would for anything else where you wanted to add handlers explicitly:

```
AddHandler engine.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf HandleSpeechRecognized
```

See the [documentation for the `AddHandler` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add error handlers in VB.NET.  You can do so "manually" by using the `AddHandler` statement, such as:

```
Dim engine As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()
AddHandler engine.SpeechDetected, AddressOf OnSpeechDetected
```

With this approach, you would then need to manually implement the `OnSpeechDetected` event handler method, such as:

```
Private Sub OnSpeechDetected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechDetectedEventArgs)
    ' Do something
End Sub
```

However, the second method is often easier.  This second method is the way that events for controls are handled.  However, it is only possible if your object variable is declared as a field (at the class level, outside of any method).  All you need to do is add the keyword `WithEvents` before the variable name, such as:

```
Dim WithEvents engine As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()
```

Then, that variable name will show up in the left-side drop-down box at the top of your code window along with all your controls.  When you select it in that drop-down box, you can then select any of its events in the right-side drop-down box and it will automatically create the event handler method for you:

```
Private Sub engine_SpeechDetected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechDetectedEventArgs) Handles engine.SpeechDetected

End Sub
```